# Copying all elements of a map into another

Tags: dictionary, go, copy

Given

```
var dst, src map[K]V
```

I can copy all entries from `src` into `dst` by doing

```
for k, v := range src {
    dst[k] = v
}
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

`copy` only works on slices (and `string` as a source).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That looks like a perfectly fine way to do this to me. I don't think copying one map into another is common enough to have a one-liner solution.

Comment: "I don't think copying one map into another is common enough"... that is my main pet peeve with go. That is something really easy to do on native types on every other language out there.

Comment: @EduFelipe I agree. The special nature of Go's built-in generic types (e.g. maps), and the lack of any way to get the same sort of functionality in user-defined types (e.g. no support for generics), is one of my biggest issues with Go. And it's just one of the many reasons why I love Rust.

Comment: Isn't there a significant performance cost to the proposed solution, as compared to a hypothetical built-in function that would simply memcopy the hashtable?

Comment: Take a look at [DeepCopy](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/rog-go/exp/deepcopy)

Comment: Copying one map into another is not common enough? I respectfully disagree.

Comment: I have to disagree as well. Seems more like a case of inconsiderate devs to me...

Comment: When you write tests, and need to aim for high path coverage - it's a lot simpler if there's just ONE path through the method code.   Rather than having to cater for the paths through all these little inline hacks that cover for missing methods.  THAT's the cost of skimping on core library methods.

Answer (score 10):

Using a simple `for range` loop is the most efficient solution.

Note that a builtin `copy` could not just copy the memory of `src` to the address of `dst` because they may have entirely different memory layout. Maps grow to accommodate the number of items stored in them. So for example if you have a map with a million elements, it occupies a lot more memory than a freshly created new map, and so a builtin `copy` could not just copy memory without allocating new.

If your map is big, you can speed up copying elements if you may create the destination map having a big-enough capacity to avoid rehashing and reallocation (the initial capacity does not bound its size), e.g.:

```
dst := make(map[K]V, len(src))

for k, v := range src {
    dst[k] = v
}
```

Starting with Go 1.18, we can create a generic solution:

```
func MapCopy[M1 ~map[K]V, M2 ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](dst M1, src M2) {
    for k, v := range src {
        dst[k] = v
    }
}
```

Testing it:

```
m1 := map[int]string{1: "one", 2: "two"}
m2 := map[int]string{}
MapCopy(m2, m1)
fmt.Println(m2)

m3 := map[string]int{"one": 1, "two": 2}
m4 := map[string]int{}
MapCopy(m4, m3)
fmt.Println(m4)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LyS7zRjzqD2)):

```
map[1:one 2:two]
map[one:1 two:2]
```

This copy function is also available at [`golang.org/x/exp/maps.Copy()`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Copy).

---

Pre 1.18 "generic" solution follows:

If performance is not an issue (e.g. you're working with small maps), a general solution may be created using the [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) package:

```
func MapCopy(dst, src interface{}) {
    dv, sv := reflect.ValueOf(dst), reflect.ValueOf(src)

    for _, k := range sv.MapKeys() {
        dv.SetMapIndex(k, sv.MapIndex(k))
    }
}
```

This solution does not check if the arguments are really maps and if the destination is not `nil`. This outputs the same, try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/4ZnIZE0-wV).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [github.com/linkosmos/mapop](https://github.com/linkosmos/mapop)

```
input :=  map[string]interface{}{
  "Key1": 2,
  "key3": nil,
  "val": 2,
  "val2": "str",
  "val3": 4,
}

input2 := map[string]interface{}{
  "a2": "str",
  "a3": 4,
}

input = mapop.Merge(input, input2)

input{"Key1": 2, "key3": nil, "val": 2, "val2": "str", "val3": 4, "a2": "str", "a3": 4}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Go 1.21

Same as below, but [`maps.Copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/maps#Copy) is now in the standard library, you can just use that instead of importing experimental packages or rolling your own.

#### Go 1.18

Use the generic function [`maps.Copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Copy)

> Copy copies all key/value pairs in src adding them to dst. When a key in src is already present in dst, the value in dst will be overwritten by the value associated with the key in src.

You use it as such:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/exp/maps"
)

func main() {

    src := map[int]string{200: "foo", 300: "bar"}
    dest := map[int]string{}

    maps.Copy(dest, src)
    fmt.Println(dest) // map[200:foo 300:bar]

    dest2 := map[int]string{200: "will be overwritten"}
    maps.Copy(dest2, src)
    fmt.Println(dest2) // map[200:foo 300:bar]
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/of_H-YaEtir

Note that the `maps` package is in `golang.org/x/exp/maps`, which is still *exp*erimental — i.e. outside of Go compatibility guarantee. Hopefully it will be moved into the standard lib at some point in the near future.

If you don't want to import `exp` packages, the function can be trivially written with Go 1.18 type parameters. The following code is identical to the `maps` source:

```
func Copy[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](dst, src M) {
    for k, v := range src {
        dst[k] = v
    }
}
```

---

At the time of writing, there is ongoing discussion to add two map type parameters to the `Copy` function, so it would become like this:

```
func Copy[M1, M2 ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](dst M1, src M2) {
    for k, v := range src {
        dst[k] = v
    }
}
```

This is functionally the same thing, as the type parameters `K` and `V` are the same for both `M1` and `M2` but brings the signature in line with the other functions in the `maps` package.