# Assigning map to a map in Golang

Tags: go, maps

Im creating and pre-filling a similar sub map and then when I assign it, I see that I have ended up referencing the same variable.

You can check it out [here](https://play.golang.org/p/hX6SJW6svb)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "strconv"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    var hour map[string]map[string]string
    var minutes map[string]string

    minutes = make(map[string]string)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        iString := strconv.Itoa(i)
        minutes[iString] = "EMPTY"
    }
    fmt.Println("Minutes")
    fmt.Println(minutes)

    hour = make(map[string]map[string]string)
    for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
        iString := strconv.Itoa(i)
        hour[iString] = make(map[string]string)
        hour[iString] = minutes
    }
    fmt.Println("Hour")
    fmt.Println(hour)

    hour["0"]["1"] = "FULL"
    fmt.Println("Modified Hour")
    fmt.Println(hour)
}
```

So, it is clear that both `hour["0"]["1"]` and `hour["1"]["1"]` have been modified.

In this case, one way is to copy the map `minutes` into the new map that I had created for every hour. Is **this** the only way?

If yes, then [copying maps over a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436864/go-copying-all-elements-of-a-map-into-another) is the best approach. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, one way is to copy the map minutes into the new map that I had created for every hour. Is this the only way?

Yes. What else could work? Go has no notion of copy-on-write or that like.

> If yes, then copying maps over a for loop is the best approach. Is that correct?

Yes. (But depends on your definition of "best").